# Neo4jClient: Wild char Search do not work when parametarized

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am having a strange issue with the Neo4JClient.

The following query works

`.AndWhere("((shipper.Name =~ '(?i).*" + filterTxt + ".*') OR (frm.Name =~ '(?i).*" + filterTxt + ".*') OR (to.Name =~ '(?i).*" + filterTxt + ".*'))");`

but the same when I convert to the parameterized query like below:

`.AndWhere("((shipper.Name =~ {searchParam}) OR (frm.Name =~ {searchParam}) OR (to.Name =~ {searchParam}))")
.WithParam("searchParam", "(?i).*" + filterTxt + ".*");`

it fails to execute from within the Neo4JClient I get an exception saying connection is closed, however when I pickup the `DebugQueryText` generated by the Neo4JClient, and execute it on the neo4j console, it returns result.

is there something I am doing wrong with the way I am using this wildcard search?

Regrads
Kiran

Comment: Looks good to me at least. Perhaps @tathamoddie has an idea?

Comment: Hi Kiran, I'm unable to replicate this, using Neo4jClient 1.0.0.661, the gist here: https://gist.github.com/cskardon/c59208ab13d2e8777494 works with both the paramaterized and non-paramaterized versions. The only real difference between mine and yours is I use `string.Format`, but I imagine that makes little difference

Comment: @ChrisSkardon: Thanks, I upgreated to 1.0.0.661 from 1.0.0.658 and its working now.